# Probability of Not Being Caught of Cheating

Tags: probability

Suppose that there is a website on Internet. There are n number of students in a university class and you are the 1 one of n students. Probability of each person who may enter this website is 1/2. If at least two students enter this website, they are all being caught of cheating. What is the probability that you won't be caught of cheating given that you already entered this website?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Are you saying that entering the website is automatically cheating?  Are you saying that the only way to avoid getting caught (given that you are in the website) is for all the other students to stay off the website?

Comment: I am saying that --> the only way to avoid getting caught (given that you are in the website) is for all the other students to stay off the website?

Comment: Ok, so then, yes.  The probability that you do not get caught is $\frac 1{2^{n-1}}$.  And then, of course, the probability that you are caught is $1-\frac 1{2^{n-1}}$ which is not what you wrote.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I couldn't understand what is the result of the binomial distribution for this problem. Assume that not being caught = p = 1/2 (probability of succes) .                             n is the number of Bernoulli trials and number of students at the same time. Then what is the meaning of choosing k as 1. P(1 succes in n trials) = n*(1/2)^n

Answer (score 0):

I found following probability but I am not sure whether it is correct or not:

**1/2^(n-1) , if n=1**

**1/2^(n) , otherwise**

Comment: You assumed the case that you entered the internet. I think it must be $n-1$ instead of $n$. So the general solution must be $1/2^{n-1}$